# How to render a container behind another container with a greater height? Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I achieve rendering a container behind another container with a greater height in flutter? The challenge I'm facing is that I'm unsure about the dynamic height of the upper container, as it's calculated at runtime. For a visual reference of the desired behavior, I've provided an accompanying image. [image]

Here is the code for rendering the top box ->

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quotifyr/configs/theme/theme.dart';

class QuotifyrBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  const QuotifyrBottomSheet({
    super.key,
    this.child,
    this.height,
    this.width,
  });

  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final QuotifyrColors colors =
        Theme.of(context).extension<QuotifyrColors>()!;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colors.surface,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
            offset: const Offset(0, -4),
            blurRadius: 16,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Unable to render a container behind another container with greater height.

Comment: Usually we use a Stack.  Have you tried a Stack?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a stack, you just have to provide the different heights for each container. For example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final QuotifyrColors colors =
    Theme.of(context).extension<QuotifyrColors>()!;
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Stack(children: [
  // What you want to be on the bottom
  Positioned(
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    child: Container(
        height: 600, //put prefered height here
        width: width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
            color: colors.primary)),
  ),

  // What you want to be on the top
  Positioned(
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    child: Container(
      height: 500, //put prefered height here
      width: width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20), topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
          color: colors.primary),
      child: child,
    ),
  ),
]);
```

}

Hope that helps

Comment: This does't solve the issue, as I mentioned in the post. The height is unknown as it's calculated at runtime.